# What's the difference between Variable and ResourceVariable in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

In Tensorflow, `Variable` is a resource, inherited from `ResourceBase` and managed by `ResourceMgr`. But why is there another named `ResourceVariable`? Both of them can be used for optimizers like `gradient_descent` (see this [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/gradient_descent_test.py)). What's the difference? I know the former is well documented and most often used. What's the purpose of the latter?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`ResourceVariable` is the replacement for `Variable`, that aims to clean up some of the messier aspects of the semantics of `Variable`.

`ResourceVariable` is the default in TF 2.0 and you very likely don't care about the differences between the two unless you are working on details deep inside the Tensorflow implementation. When eager execution is enabled `tf.Variable` also creates resource variables.

So just use `tf.Variable` for now, it's almost certainly what you want; if you experience issues which look like race conditions or bugs from inconsistent values of variables in code you can try enabling resource variables (by either passing `use_resource=True` to your variable-creating code or calling `tf.enable_resource_variables()` in TF 1.x).

Answer (score 8):

From the comments:

> Unlike tf.Variable, a tf.ResourceVariable has well-defined semantics.
>   Each usage of a ResourceVariable in a TensorFlow graph adds a
>   read_value operation to the graph. The Tensors returned by a
>   read_value operation are guaranteed to see all modifications to the
>   value of the variable which happen in any operation on which the
>   read_value depends on (either directly, indirectly, or via a control
>   dependency) and guaranteed to not see any modification to the value of
>   the variable on which the read_value operation does not depend on. 
>   For example, if there is more than one assignment to a
>   ResourceVariable in a single session.run call there is a well-defined
>   value for each operation which uses the variable's value if the
>   assignments and the read are connected by edges in the graph. Consider
>   the following example, in which two writes can cause tf.Variable and
>   tf.ResourceVariable to behave differently:

```
a = tf.ResourceVariable(1.0)
a.initializer.run()
assign = a.assign(2.0)
with tf.control_dependencies([assign]):
    b = a.read_value()
with tf.control_dependencies([b]):
    other_assign = a.assign(3.0)
with tf.control_dependencies([other_assign]):
    # Will print 2.0 because the value was read before other_assign ran. If
    # `a` was a tf.Variable instead, 2.0 or 3.0 could be printed.
    tf.Print(b, [b]).eval()
```

> To enforce these consistency properties tf.ResourceVariable might
>   make more   copies than an equivalent tf.Variable under the hood, so
>   tf.Variable is still   not deprecated.

Comment: Which comments are you referring to?

Comment: Probably this one: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/838a8f54f92452a15e3bb62a23ad5cd67e86933f/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py#L168-L194

Comment: I can't find the docs for `tf.ResourceVariable` on tensorflow.org for tf1.10. Was this removed in a later release? If yes, does the implementation of `tf.Variable`solve the issues mentioned above?