# Interconversion and difference

Tags: loops, tensorflow, type-conversion, tensor

I have two types of tensors.

```
1) <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable'>
2) <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

What is the difference between the two? Can interconversion be done? In particular if I want to convert the second type to first type.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor) is basically a multidimensional array of elements, while a `tf.ResourceVariable` is pretty much like a [fancier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40817665/14774959) [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable). I think they were used in Tensorflow 1, but in Tf2 got removed, I can't even find them in the documentation (are you using tf1?).

Let's just talk about variables, that can be used similarly. The `tf.Variable` is a wrapper around a tensor, so you can initialize the variable using the tensor, as we will see below.

Having a `tf.Variable` (here to [learn more](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variable?hl=en)) adds further capabilities to the tensor. An important distinction is that the `tf.Variable` maintains state across multiple runs. The variable is pretty much used to represent the trainable parameters of the model, while the tensor is used as array to feed to the network.

So as I was saying, a `tf.Variable` stores a persistent tensor and can be initialized using that `tf.Tensor` like this:

```
variable = tf.Variable(my_tensor)
```

Comment: I am using 2.8.2 version of tf. Yes the resource variable type are still available. Actually they are the weight/bias types of layers of a keras model instance. I actully did some modeifications in weights of these layers and obtained the second type, i.e., <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>.  The model instance is not processing these so I had to convert them to first type. It still is not working though